# Can you declare multiple reference variables on the same line in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

I.e. are these legal statements:

```
int x = 1, y = z = 2;
int& a = x, b = c = y;
```

with the intended result that `a` is an alias for `x`, while`b` and `c` are aliases for `y`?

I ask simply because I read [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html)

> Declaring a variable as a reference rather than a normal variable
>   simply entails appending an ampersand to the **type** name

which lead me to hesitate whether it was legal to create multiple reference variables by placing `&` before the **variable** name.

Comment: is your compiler broken?

Comment: Hint: it's like pointers.

Comment: No - just wanted to check in caution before writing the code.

Comment: @MiloChen, A simple test on the compiler would tell you. All you have to do is change x, y, and z, and then print a, b, and c.

Comment: Note that `int& a, b;` declares `a`, a reference-to-int, and `b`, an int.  The `&` must be specified for each declared variable, just like `*` or `[]`.

Comment: don't write code like this please.

Comment: Pray Tell - Why are you writing such crap code? Job security perhaps?!

Comment: I simply got confused by the tutorial at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html, which emphasizes appending an ampersand to the **type** name with the example given as `int& foo = ....;`.

Comment: @MiloChen, Perhaps it's time for a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @MiloChen This is exactly why I advocate for the opposite placement: `int &foo = ...;`.  But the real answer is "don't declare more than one variable at a time."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int x = 1, y = z = 2;--incorrect
int& a = x, b = c = y;--incorrect
```

The statements should be like this:

```
int x = 1, y =2,z = 2;
int&q=x,&b=y,&c=y;
```

All assignment and initialization statements in c++ should be of the following type:

```
lvalue=rvalue;
```

here lvalue must always be a variable to which a temporary value/another variable is assigned.
rvalue can be another variable or an expression that evaluates to a temporary variable like (4+5).

Comment: I believe you have a word spelled incorretly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to append a & on the left of each reference (like you would need a * when you declare a pointer).